# As soon as a single element wraps have the rest of the elements wrap as well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has a section of inline-blocks and what I'm trying to accomplish is for them all to be on the same row if they will fit but as soon as one of the wraps I want them all to wrap onto new lines. I have an idea for some continuous javascript position/width checking but I'm hoping there's something a bit cleaner built into CSS or bootstrap for this.

Edit: To clarify a bit-
Each block's width is variable and will not change after page load.
The container's width is variable and may change after page load (resizing the browser window / mobile orientation changes).

Heres an example fiddle where the first container is the correct expected behaviour but the bottom container I want everything to wrap:
https://jsfiddle.net/bxye0L4L/1/

```
<div class="wide-container">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block two"></div>
  <div class="block three"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="narrow-container">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block two"></div>
  <div class="block three"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wide-container {
  width: 700px;
  border: black solid;
}
.narrow-container {
  width: 500px;
  border: black solid;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: I would say that without media query or hacks it's not possible... so are you intresting with media query or hacks ?

Comment: Just research "responsive design"

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there are 2 straigtforward css options.

a) make the "narrow container" narrower - reduce from 500px to e.g 350 or 300

or

b) you could make a separate css class for the bottom container and set them to block if you want them to line up one under another.

Is there a reason for the narrow one to be 500? If so I'd go for the second option. I include snippets

```css
.wide-container {
  width: 700px;
  border: black solid;
}

.narrow-container {
  width: 500px;
  border: black solid;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.iblock {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 3px 0px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide-container">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block two"></div>
  <div class="block three"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="narrow-container">
  <div class="iblock one"></div>
  <div class="iblock two"></div>
  <div class="iblock three"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.wide-container {
  width: 700px;
  border: black solid;
}
.narrow-container {
  width: 300px;
  border: black solid;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide-container">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block two"></div>
  <div class="block three"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="narrow-container">
  <div class="block one"></div>
  <div class="block two"></div>
  <div class="block three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the options are posted in reverse order - oops

Comment: Unfortunately only works for a fixed container width. The wide-container and narrow-container was an attempt to show the same container in multiple states.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood the question then. Consider flex-box maybe?